# how to get largest date with the last value in status Powerbi

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi, dax

I have a table with column name (action_date) I want to get the latest date when status  (Approve) (action_code)
I have in the action_code column more than one approves value. I have composed unique columns (Request_number) and (sequence_number)
Please note that: each sequence equal value status EX: seq: 1 status: submit seq:2 status: Approve...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDDkA.png)

Comment: Please read about creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   Then update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select request_number, max(action_date)
from table
where action_code = 'APPROVE'
group by request_number;
```